# Vue.js: use setTimeout function changing input value?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm the very beginning of `Vue.js`, I just meeting `v-model` part, here is the code:

HTML:
`<div id="app">
  <p> {{message}} </p>
  <input v-model="message" id="input_id">
</div>`

javascript:

```
var v = new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data:{
    message: "Hello"
  }
});

var inputDOM = document.querySelector('#input_id');

setTimeout(function(){
  inputDOM.value = "Changing By timeout";
},1500);
```

Yes, when I type some text in `input` tag, the `innerHTML` of `<p>` will change as long as I type. 
BUT
If I use `setTimeout` function to change the value of `input` tag, the `innerHTMl` of `<p>` won't change.
and yes, if use `setTimeout` function to change the value of `data` object, the `input` value will as long as change.

here is the `vue.js` I include:
`<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>`
and here is the demo on [codepen.io](http://codepen.io/FlyC/pen/eBLzxE?editors=1010)

Without any purpose indeed, so I don't need any other solution to handle that two-way binding, just a little bit curious why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you type inside the input box, the changes are handled by the getter / setter methods of Vue, as explained in this page: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

In the above case, input box is within the Vue app. Therefore Vue is able to set up its getter / setter methods to handle those changes.

When the anonymous function runs within `setTimeout`, it is done outside the Vue app. The value of input box gets changed directly using javascript, but **outside the scope** of Vue app. Therefore its getter / setter methods are not triggered. And therefore the changes are not reflected in your Vue template.

Comment: thanks! I guess that if I wanna use `javascript` to change the value and also trigger getter / setter methods of Vue, I have to use some kind of `:value` or something else. I gonna keep reading Guide page, thanks again!